# How to create Athena schema using AWS Glue Crawler classifier from JSON?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am using a simple JSON format like this:

```
[{"key":"value"},{"key":"value"}]
```

When I set JSON path to $[*] and run a crawler, it creates the schema correctly but does not read the data properly.

I played around the JSON file and removed outer brackets [], it only reads the first row (as it is no longer an array). It seems like JSON file should look like below to work in AWS Athena:

```
{"key":"value"}
{"key":"value"}
```

Is there anyway I can read JSON file in this format by configuring JSON path in AWS Glue?

Comment: So far I don't think there is a way to use regular expressions to parse JSON data so temporarily I decided to transform JSON to parquet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it did not read the data properly first time, because you need to put the file under a folder. All the files which are part of the same table should be located inside the same folder. If you put multiple different files in same S3 location, crawler will be able to identify the schema properly; but querying the table won't return any data. This is one of the many gotchas using AWS Glue. I have recently written a blog about it. Here is the [link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/my-top-5-gotchas-working-aws-glue-tanveer-uddin/) if that helps.